# Prevent ajax auto complete from running with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an auto complete ajax script that runs when characters are typed into a field. I want to prevent this from running when a toggle is clicked to allow manual completion. I'm trying to use .unbind but its not working?

```
function manualEntry() {
 jQuery("#field_41_47").toggle();
 if (jQuery('#field_41_47').css('display') == 'none') {
      jQuery('#manual-company-entry').html('Enter company manually');
      jQuery("#field_41_47").hide();
      jQuery('#input_41_44').val('').change();
 }
 else {
      jQuery('#manual-company-entry').html('Search for company');
      jQuery("#field_41_47").show();
      jQuery('#input_41_44').val(1).change();
      xhr.unbind();
 }
}
```

Comment: a simple solution is to use a global variable with true/false. Use your toggle to change the value and test it at the top of your ajax function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you show me an example?

Comment: actually checking your history there, you need to review your previous questions and accept answers if appropriate. Upvote if the answer helped you etc.

Answer (score 0):

example simple setup (this is based on jsfiddle ajax so dont expect it to work without changing the $.ajax function)

html

```
<input type="button" id="completetoggle" value="toggle auto complete on/off">

<input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield">
<div id="target" ><div>
```

js

```
$(document).on('click', '#completetoggle', function(){
        toggle= ((toggle === true) ? false : true);          
    });

    $(document).on('keyup', '#textfield', function() {

        if(toggle===true) {
            text=$('#textfield').val();
            var returned = ajaxtext(text);
            returned.done(function(html) {
                $('#target').html(html);
            });
        }    
    });

    ajaxtext= function(text){
       return $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html/', 
        type: 'post',      
           data: {html: text},     
        cache: false
        }); 
    };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mh5f5Le5/1/